# Where does Magento implement methods?

Tags: blocks, template, magento-1, code, methods

I am new to Magento. I have following code in a template file called `brand.html`

```
$brandImageUrl = $this->getBrandImageUrl($brand);
```

My understanding (roughly) is that `$this` refers to an instance of the block created by `brand.html`

Basically the image path returned by that method refers to an image that is too small and I would like to know where this method is is implemented so I can modify it to give me a path to a larger image. The image in question is a brand logo, currently at 40x19 pixels, which is too small.

Any pointers in the right direction are very welcome. Also general information for Magento newbies is welcome.

P.S. I have been programming for many years in many languages on many systems, but Magento is baffling me.

Comment: get_class($this)

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities here:

### Block method

The `getBrandImageUrl` is a method defined in the block.

To find out the class of the block you can call:

```
get_class($this);
```

### Magic method

The method `getBrandImageUrl` is a magic getter.

Thus it is not explicitely declared anywhere in the code.

As most of the Magento classes extend `Varien_Object` the code that makes that method available can be found under `lib/Varien/Object.php` :

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
        case 'get' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $data;

        case 'set' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->setData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'uns' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->unsetData($key);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'has' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return isset($this->_data[$key]);
    }
    throw new Varien_Exception("Invalid method ".get_class($this)."::".$method."(".print_r($args,1).")");
}
```

The first case is the magic getter, next one is magic setter, then magic unsetter and finally magic has.

So in that case, the block is being assigned a `brand_image_url` dynamically by one of the following call:

```
$block->setBrandImageUrl($foo);
$block->setData('brand_image_url', $foo);
```